# Allow "Force.com – One App” license Users to create Contacts

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

We have developed an App with one of the feature that allows Users to create Contacts if no Contact is found on search. But as we know the Users assigned under "Force.com-One App" license have only READ-ONLY access to Contact object, and as in our instance there are many Users assigned with "Force.com-One App" license who needs to be provided with the feature to create new Contacts if they are not able to find one. Is this possible by any mean of coding, or API or ...? Will highly appreciate for any suggestion.
(Please comment if you have any doubts/queries)

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your question that app user has only read only permission.
However following options are available:

1. You can identify few users who want to create contacts and buy force.com app license for them, these licenses are also affordable.
2. You can create custom object to mimic contact and create actual contact record using scheduler and delete dummy record. However this solution has lots of loopholes and be ready to face lots of development effort.
   I would suggest to go with option 1.

Comment: Thank you Jitendra. Yes, the last option we have is to go with (1), however as per the requirement in our App, the User should be able to immediately  use the newly created Contact to perform some actions... so guess (2) won't be effective in that scenario.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any other option. Please mark it if answered your question.